# CoreData NSPredicate MATCHES regex

Tags: objective-c, regex, core-data, nspredicate

I have a CoreData table with a field holding a string of a series of numbers separated by commas. I want to be able to run a fetch with a predicate that will match against a given specific number.

For example if fieldName = "12,52,66,89,2,8"

And I want to search for 2, then it should match the second to last number in the string and include that record in the results.

Using the regular expression:
^2|,2,|,2
I have found it working satisfactorily for my test cases, testing it using this site for example: https://www.regexpal.com/

However, when I pass this into an NSPredicate for a NSFetchRequest, I can't get it to match

```
NSNumber *val = @2;
NSString *regex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^%@|,%@,|,%@", val, val, val];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fieldName MATCHES %@", regex];
```

Replacing the MATCHES with a CONTAINS val makes it work, but of course it will also incorrectly match any occurrence of the digits.

I suspect I am missing something stupid about formatting for CoreData (or regex), but I've tried many variations, and I'm hoping a kind soul reading this will put me out of my misery :)

Comment: In `"12,52,66,89,2,8"`, you match only `,2,` your regex needs to match the whole string. Else, it returns not a match in the search.

Comment: Thanks @Larme, this is resolved now, see my comments on the accepted answer below. In the end I had two errors - 1. Thinking that any match would count as a match for the fetchrequest predicate, and 2. Not escaping the escape characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't used Objective C. This answer is based on my regex knowledge and [some documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

> MATCHES
>   The left hand expression equals the right hand expression using a regex-style comparison according to ICU v3 (for more details see the ICU User Guide for Regular Expressions).

That sounds like how Java uses the method "matches" in which case "^2|,2,|,2" can never match the entire string. This differs from regexpal which will always search the text. The regex you would need is more like

```
.*\b2\b.*
```

(the ^$ are assumed in Java). Another option is to split the string.

Comment: Thanks for this, you might be right about the notion that it requires a match on the entire string as opposed to finding any match, I'll investigate that further! (Your example isn't working correctly either although it does look like it should, I wonder if the word boundary definition is the reason).

Comment: I'm doing more tests but I believe this has lead to the solution - another issue was that the regex backslashes need escaping. I am testing now with  NSString *regex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*\\b%@\\b.*", val];